# downloadURL state change inside a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, firebase, state, firebase-storage

I'm uploading a series o images to the firebase storage, and I need all the URL's of those images to link to in firebase Database. This is the code i'm using so far:

```
var imgArray = []

      for (var i=0; i < document.getElementById("myFile").files.length; i++){

        var selectedFile = document.getElementById("myFile").files[i];

        var selectedStorageRef = firebase.storage().ref(this.estado + "/" + this.cidade + "/" + document.getElementById("nome-do-pico").value + "/" + selectedFile.name);

        var uploadTask = selectedStorageRef.put(selectedFile);


        uploadTask.on('state_changed', null, null, function (snapshot){
          var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
          imgArray.push(downloadURL);
          console.log(imgArray);

          });

      }
```

The idea is to get them all in an array first, but I always gets just the last URL. If I try to upload 3 images for example sometimes I even get an array of [null, URL, URL] or [null, null, URL]. I rarely get 3 URL's, and in every case they are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remove the `var` at the beginning of the downloadURL declaration?

Comment: Nope, the problem remains even without the var :(

Answer (score 0):

The `.put()` method returns a promise, you should use the `.then()` method to do the push on the array.

Something like this:

```
var imgArray = []

      for (var i=0; i < document.getElementById("myFile").files.length; i++){
        var selectedFile = document.getElementById("myFile").files[i];
        var selectedStorageRef = firebase.storage().ref(this.estado + "/" + this.cidade + "/" + document.getElementById("nome-do-pico").value + "/" + selectedFile.name);
        var uploadTask = selectedStorageRef.put(selectedFile).then( snapshot => {
          var downloadURL = selectedStorageRef.getDownloadURL().then( urlSnap => {
              imgArray.push(urlSnap.val());
              console.log(imgArray);
          });
      });
}
```

Comment: When I do this it gives me an error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'downloadURL' of undefined

Comment: No problem bro. Just a question, after the second .then is it really a _> or a =>? Cause I've never seen the _> ever, haha. Anyway, tested both but sadly had no luck. I got a "Uncaught TypeError: urlSnap.val is not a function
    at selectedStorageRef.getDownloadURL.then.urlSnap"

Comment: No, it was just a typo. Try it without the `.val()`. I've got a mess in my head with the snapshots and the promises.

Comment: So, the weirdest thing just happend. When I try to upload 3 or more files it gives me an error saying that the the the "Firebase Storage: Object 'DF/brasilia/test/IMG_0168.PNG' does not exist.". When I try with just 2 files, it still just gives me an array with two equal entries, the last file's URL

Comment: Maybe it was the internet connection. Try to do it again. Seems like it's not uploading the image. Check the console to see if it's there.

Comment: Even if it is an internet connection problem, i keep getting just the last file's URL

Comment: Problem is it's iterating over the files quickly and since the upload is an asynchronous task, it takes the value of the variable when it's already iterated over all of the files. Maybe storing the refs on an array